# How can i get an image of windows server 16 using docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, windows-server-2016

I am thinking to get an **image of windows server 16** using docker on windows 10 platform. Is it possible to get or should i try it on windows server 16 only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why create Windows server docker image if you can download one from Docker Hub?

To pull the official image, just run the command:

```
$ docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore
```

It will download the latest version of Windows server core, which as of this writing is 2016. Supported Windows Server 2016 (Long Term Support Channel) tags are:

```
ltsc2016, latest
10.0.14393.<Revision Number>
10.0.14393.<Revision Number>_<Language Code>
```

Once you have the image local on your machine, you can create your custom images using Dockerfile. To learn how to work with Dockerfiles, visit [Aquasec Working with Dockerfiles](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Working+With+Dockerfiles) documentation.

Also, reference the official [Dockerfiles guide on Docker site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). You can then build custom docker image that fits your use case.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I have just corrected the question my intention was to get the image of Windows server not to create.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Got it, 
After installing docker on windows 10 we need to open the "**Windows PowerShell**" and go through this link [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/).
By using this command:- **docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore** we can get the image of Windows server 16.